# Canvas UI does not render in GVR (Google Cardboard) in Unity 5.3.5

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

**Background**

I am using Unity3D 5.3.5 to develop a Google VR (Cardboard) project

**Introduction**

I added a canvas button to my scene. It shows up in scene mode and *sometimes* in Game mode but never when I run the project

**What I have tried**

1. Turning off **Direct Render** for Main Camera
2. Setting up **Render Mode** of canvas to World Space
3. Adding Main Camera to **Event Camera**

**Observations**

1. Button shows up in Scene and Game Mode but not during Play mode
2. Though the UI does not show up, **Physics Raycaster** in the reticle hits the button.

**Screenshots Below**
[image: Screenshot of Scene and Game Mode][image: Screenshot of Canvas component][image: Screenshot of Play Mode]

Comment: There is an option of Cardboard to set a minimum distance. Objects closer to the camera than that value are hidden. Clipping mask? Sorry I don't have a computer to check.

Comment: Didn't know about the minimum distance. However, this solution did not work in my case. The canvas is at a fair distance and I found that other objects at lesser distance got rendered. Most answers on the internet suggest that it is bug of Unity version I am on. Thanks though!

Comment: Very welcome and good to know to not update unity!

Comment: So I had the same issue and upgraded to Unity 5.4 beta.  In this version the canvas shows in game mode, but the canvas is a solid bright purple when i run it on the headset...

Answer (score 1):

This is a Unity bug. In the forums [they mentioned](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/world-canvas-not-displaying-on-cardboard.396425/#post-2676767) it will be fixed in 5.3.5p5.

Its also noted in known issues for gvr:

> Starting with 5.3.4p2, a bug in Unity prevents rendering World Space
>   uGUI Canvases into a RenderTexture

https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes#v080_initial_release

It works in older version(5.3.4f1), if you need to test it right now.

Comment: Thanks! Any work around that you can suggest other than quads ?

Answer (score 0):

in your canvas **change Render Mode** to-> **Screen Space Camera**

change **Render Camera** to -> Your camera

change **Plane Distance** to a very low number but not negative

Comment: only problem i found its off by a few  :< but it does render on the screen